# Error 404 not found when pressing F5 on a page under IIS and Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: iis, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

The default Blazor WebAssembly project with the Counter page, while debugging works perfectly but after deployment if I click on Counter menu and then hit F5 the browser displays the 404 message. First deployment of a Blazor project, what am I missing?

Comment: SPA requires a rewrite rule on web server to default page. If you missed that, such 404 errors are well known for years.

Comment: Do I need to configure it in IIS or in Blazor project?

Comment: have you hosted the project as a site or the sub application in iis?

Comment: As a site, if I use a virtual directory or a sub application I get 'ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)' and 'Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received'

Answer (score 0):

could you add below code in the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir" enabled="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install last version of dotnet hosting, update Visual Studio and create a WebAssembly Project as PWA instead hosted application.